# AngularJS - ng-click reinitialising database objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am creating a dynamic, single-paged forum site using AngularJS as the front-end and Firebase as the back-end. The page consists of a list of threads on the left-hand side and the thread content on the right-hand side. The thread content displayed is based on the thread selected from the list.

I can successfully select a thread from the list and display its contents. However, when a thread is selected from the list, all of the other threads in the list become replicas of the selected thread. By this, I mean that the attribute values for the title, comments and votes of the selected thread are assigned to the same attributes in all of the other threads simultaneously, making them all identical. The ID of each thread does not change.

Can anybody give me some insight as to what is causing this issue? I can't identify anything in my code that would cause the attribute values of each Firebase object to be reassigned.

Here is the main.html page that contains the list and thread content sections

```
<div ng-controller="mainPageController">
    <div>
        <h3>
            Welcome {{user.name}}! <button class="btn-danger img-rounded" ng-click="logout()" id="LogoutBtn">Logout</button>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>All Threads</h2>
        <div id="searchThreads" class="input-group col-md-5 img-rounded">
            <input type="text" class="col-xs-5 form-control" ng-model="searchThread" placeholder="Search threads...">
        </div>
        <div id="addThread" class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="col-xs-5 form-control" ng-model="newThreadTitle" placeholder="New thread title..."/>
            <button ng-click="addThread()">Add thread</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Thread List -->
        <div>
            <div ng-repeat="thread in threads | filter:searchThread | orderObjectBy:'votes'">
                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" ng-click="upvote(thread.$id, thread.votes)"></button> | 
                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" ng-click="downvote(thread.$id, thread.votes)"></button>
                <a href ng-click="showThread(thread)">{{thread.votes}}<span style="margin-left:1em"> {{thread.title}} by {{thread.username}}</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Thread content viiew -->
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div ng-controller="threadPageController">
        <h1>{{currentThread.title}} by {{currentThread.username}}</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="newComment" placeholder="Write a comment..."/>
            <button ng-click="addComment()">Add Comment</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div ng-repeat="comment in currentThread.comments">{{comment.username}}: {{comment.text}}
            </div>
            <div ng-if="!currentThread.comments.length">There are no comments on this thread</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The mainPageController

```
angular.module('richWebApp')
.controller('mainPageController', function($scope, $location, userService, threadService, fb, $firebaseAuth, $filter){

    $scope.user = userService.getLoggedInUser();

    $scope.newThreadTitle = '';

    $scope.currentThreadId = '';

    $scope.threads = threadService.getAllThreads();

    $scope.threads.$loaded().then(function(){
        console.log($scope.threads)
    });

    $scope.users = userService.getLoggedInUsers();

    $scope.addThread = function(){  
        if(!$scope.newThreadTitle){
            return false; //Don't do anything if the text box is empty
        }
        var newThread = {       
            title: $scope.newThreadTitle,
            username: $scope.user.name,            
            comments: [],
            votes: 0
        };

        $scope.threads.$add(newThread);

        $scope.newThread = '';

        $scope.newThreadTitle = ''; //Clear the text in the input box
    }


    $scope.showThread = function(thread) {
        $scope.$emit('handleEmit', {id: thread.$id});
    };

    $scope.upvote = function(threadId, threadVotes) {
        var newVotes = threadVotes + 1;
        var ref = new Firebase(fb.url);
        var threadRef = ref.child("threads");
        threadRef.child(threadId).update({
            votes: newVotes
        });

    }

    $scope.downvote = function(threadId, threadVotes) {
        var newVotes = threadVotes - 1;
        var ref = new Firebase(fb.url);
        var threadRef = ref.child("threads");
        threadRef.child(threadId).update({
            votes: newVotes
        });

    }

    $scope.logout = function(){
        userService.logout();
    }

});
```

The threadPageController

```
angular.module('richWebApp')
.controller('threadPageController', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, threadService, fb, userService){

    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function (event, args) {
        var threadId = args.id;
        var currentThread = threadService.getThread(threadId);
        currentThread.$bindTo($scope, 'currentThread') //creates $scope.thread with 3 way binding
    });

    $scope.newComment = '';

    $scope.addComment= function(){ 
        if(!$scope.newComment){
            return false; //Don't do anything if the text box is empty
        }       

        var currentUser = userService.getLoggedInUser();

        var newComment = {
            text: $scope.newComment,
            username: currentUser.name
        };

        $scope.currentThread.comments = $scope.currentThread.comments || [];
        $scope.currentThread.comments.push(newComment);

        $scope.newComment = ''; //Clear the input box
    }
});
```

threadService

```
angular.module("richWebApp").service("threadService", function($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, fb){

    this.getAllThreads = function(){
        var ref = new Firebase(fb.url + '/threads');
        return $firebaseArray(ref);
    };

    this.getThread = function(threadId){
        var ref = new Firebase(fb.url + '/threads/' + threadId);
        return $firebaseObject(ref);
    };
});
```

Comment: can you post the code of `threadService`?

Comment: @yarons I have updated my original post to include threadService

Comment: is `showThread` what's currently running in your code? because the name of the event it emits (and the fact that you use `$emit`) doesn't fit the name of the event that `threadPageController` listens to

Comment: Yes, showThread emits the ID of the selected thread which is then used in the threadController file. The threadController file then calls the getThread method in the threadService file. The code works perfectly with regards to retrieving the values from the back-end. I originally had the threadPageController and and mainPageController merged into one large file without the
    $emit
or
    $on
and I was still having this issue so I am confident that the values being passed around are not the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear. You emit an event named `handleEmit` in the main controller, but catch an event called `handleBroadcast` in the other controller. One of them seems to be outdated.

Comment: I have configured this relationship in my app.js so that it handles all emits and broadcasts. It does work, as I said, values can be passed successfully from the main controller to the thread controller.

Comment: On the line :  currentThread.$bindTo($scope, 'currentThread') //creates $scope.thread with 3 way binding.  Your comment says thread, the bind is to $currentThread.  This raises a flag to a potential issue in some other portion of your code.

Comment: The line originally bound to "thread" and I realise now that I forgot to change the comment